# Using peewee ORM with spatialite databases?

Tags: qgis, python, spatialite

I would like to use the [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) orm in front of some Spatialite databases.  Getting peewee to connect to a Spatialite database was relatively simple, and basically boiled down to:

```
class SpatialiteDatabase(SqliteExtDatabase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpatialiteDatabase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.load_extension('mod_spatialite')

    def initialize_connection(self, conn):
        LOG.warn('initializing spatialite metadata')
        self.execute_sql('select InitSpatialMetadata(1);')

playhouse.db_url.schemes['spatialite'] = SpatialiteDatabase
```

So, great, now we can get a connection to a database with the Spatialite
extension enabled.  But I'm not clear how to create Peewee models with
geometry columns, since unlike in, say, PostGIS, Spatialite requires
the use of particular SQL functions (like `AddGeometryColumn`) to
manipulate tables.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to write a model something like this:

```
class Placemark(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = TextField()
    alias = CharField(20)
    geom = GeometryField(srid=4326, geom_type='POINT')
```

And get the equivalent of:

```
CREATE TABLE "placemark" (
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "alias" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn("placemark", "geom",
    4326, "POINT", "XY");
```

My best option so far has been to populate the geometry fields manually after the fact.

Comment: You may need to check [this](https://medium.com/a-geeks-blog/how-to-use-a-postgis-geometry-with-peewee-646217bedb38) out.